# Java heap memory error with HTMLuint

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am getting the below error when I try to access the a txt file in HTMLunit.

Code:

```
public class LogFileAutomation {
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogFileAutomation.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream("H:\\config.properties");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error in loading the external config file", e);
    }
    try {
        String readURL = null;
        String readfolderPath = null;
        String readlogFileHref = null;
        String loginURL = null;

        if (input == null) {
            System.out.println("Loading config file from classPath..");
            input = LogFileAutomation.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("config.properties");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Loading config file from external Path..");
        }
        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);
        String version = prop.getProperty("version");

        // get the property value
        if (version.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("getting into version 1");
            readURL = prop.getProperty("URLS");
            readfolderPath = prop.getProperty("folderPath");
            readlogFileHref = prop.getProperty("logFileHref");
            loginURL = prop.getProperty("oldLogin");
        } else {
            System.out.println("getting into version 2");
            readURL = prop.getProperty("NEWURLS");
            readfolderPath = prop.getProperty("newfolderPath");
            readlogFileHref = prop.getProperty("newlogFileHref");
            loginURL = prop.getProperty("newLogin");
        }
        String URLS[] = readURL.split(",");
        String folderPath[] = readfolderPath.split(",");
        String logFileHref[] = readlogFileHref.split(",");

        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(10000);

        HtmlPage page = null;

        System.out.println("Please enter the Login details below.");

        /**
         * Getting user details.
         */

        System.out.println("Username:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String username = scanner.next();
        String password = new LogFileAutomation().getPassword();

        page = webClient.getPage(loginURL);

        HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("PWChange");

        HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("BUTTON");
        HtmlTextInput usernameHTMLInput = form.getInputByName("USER");

        /**
         * Password got assigned
         */
        Page passwordHTMLInput = form.getInputByName("PASSWORD")
                .setValueAttribute(password.trim());

        /**
         * User name got assigned
         */
        usernameHTMLInput.setValueAttribute(username);

        webClient.setRefreshHandler(new ThreadedRefreshHandler());
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

        DomNodeList<DomElement> statusTable = page2
                .getElementsByTagName("table");

        String pageTitle = page2.getTitleText();

        /**
         * Checking that we landed in correct scraping page.
         */
        if (!pageTitle.equals("Corporate Systems ESS Password Services")) {
            logPageContent(webClient, statusTable, logFileHref[0],
                    folderPath[0], version);

            for (int r = 0; r < URLS.length; r++) {
                HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage(URLS[r].toString());

                DomNodeList<DomElement> logTable = page1
                        .getElementsByTagName("table");

                logPageContent(webClient, logTable, logFileHref[r + 1],
                        folderPath[r + 1], version);

            }
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("Please enter correct username and password..");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException occured in Main method: " + e);
        saveLogException(e, "IOException occured in Main method: ");
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException se) {
        System.out
                .println("FailingHttpStatusCodeException occured in Main method: "
                        + se.getMessage());
        saveLogException(se,
                "FailingHttpStatusCodeException occured in Main method: ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Generic exception occured in Main method: "
                + e.getMessage());
        saveLogException(e, "Generic exception occured in Main method: ");
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out
                        .println("IOException occured in finally try catch Main method: "
                                + e.getMessage());
                saveLogException(e,
                        "IOException occured in finally try catch Main method: ");
            }
        }
    }

}

/**
 * This method is to get the log page content to scrap the information..
 * 
 * @param webClient
 *            - contains the webClient.
 * @param logTable
 *            - contains the log page table HTML information.
 * @param logFileHref
 *            - contains the log file HREF link from where we have to down
 *            load the file.
 * @param folderPath
 *            - contains the folder path where we have to down load the
 *            file.
 */
private static void logPageContent(WebClient webClient,
        DomNodeList<DomElement> logTable, String logFileHref,
        String folderPath, String version) {
    System.out.println("version"+version);
    try {
        for (int k = 0; k < logTable.size(); k++) {
            /*
             * logPageContent(webClient, statusTable, k, folderPath[0],
             * logFileHref[0]);
             */

            DomNodeList<HtmlElement> statusTable1 = logTable.get(k)
                    .getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (int u = 0; u < statusTable1.size(); u++) {
                DomNodeList<HtmlElement> statusTD = statusTable1.get(u)
                        .getElementsByTagName("td");

                for (int i = 0; i < statusTD.size(); i++) {
                    Iterable<DomElement> innerContent = statusTD.get(i)
                            .getChildElements();

                    String fileModifiedDate[] = statusTD.get(1)
                            .getTextContent().split(" ");
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "dd-MMM-yyyy");
                    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
                    Date date = new Date();
                    String currentDate = df.format(date);
                    if (fileModifiedDate[0].equals(currentDate)) {
                        for (DomElement y : innerContent) {

                            if (y.getTagName().equals("a")) {
                                if (version.equals("1")) {
                                    String filnameStartsWith = "sp";
                                    String filnameStartsWith1 = "sy";
                                    String filnameStartsWith2 = "na";
                                    String filnameStartsWith3 = "impaqsws2RISC";
                                    if (filnameStartsWith.startsWith(y
                                            .getTextContent().substring(0,
                                                    2))
                                            || filnameStartsWith1
                                                    .startsWith(y
                                                            .getTextContent()
                                                            .toLowerCase()
                                                            .substring(0, 2))
                                            || filnameStartsWith2
                                                    .startsWith(y
                                                            .getTextContent()
                                                            .substring(0, 2))
                                            || filnameStartsWith3
                                                    .startsWith(y
                                                            .getTextContent()
                                                            .substring(0, 2))) {

                                        TextPage page1 = webClient
                                                .getPage(logFileHref
                                                        + y.getAttributeNode(
                                                                "href")
                                                                .getNodeValue());
                                        System.out
                                                .println("Downlaoding: "
                                                        + logFileHref
                                                        + y.getAttributeNode(
                                                                "href")
                                                                .getNodeValue());
                                        exportFile(page1,
                                                y.getTextContent(),
                                                folderPath);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    String filnameStartsWith = "sp";
                                    String filnameStartsWith1 = "sy";
                                    String filnameStartsWith2 = "na";
                                    String filnameStartsWith3 = "impaqsws2RISC";
                                    String filnameStartsWith4 = "id";
                                    if (filnameStartsWith.startsWith(y
                                            .getTextContent().substring(0,
                                                    2))
                                            || filnameStartsWith1
                                                    .startsWith(y
                                                            .getTextContent()
                                                            .toLowerCase()
                                                            .substring(0, 2))
                                            || filnameStartsWith2
                                                    .startsWith(y
                                                            .getTextContent()
                                                            .substring(0, 2))
                                            || filnameStartsWith3
                                                    .startsWith(y
                                                            .getTextContent()
                                                            .substring(0, 2))
                                            || filnameStartsWith4
                                                    .startsWith(y
                                                            .getTextContent()
                                                            .substring(0, 2))) {

                                        TextPage page1 = webClient
                                                .getPage(logFileHref
                                                        + y.getAttributeNode(
                                                                "href")
                                                                .getNodeValue());
                                        System.out
                                                .println("Downlaoding: "
                                                        + logFileHref
                                                        + y.getAttributeNode(
                                                                "href")
                                                                .getNodeValue());
                                        exportFile(page1,
                                                y.getTextContent(),
                                                folderPath);
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            if (folderPath.contains("metintugpar0635")) {
                TextPage page1 = webClient
                        .getPage("https://****/view/ezspprodportal1/ezspPROD/WebSphere_Portal/SystemOut.log");
                exportFile(page1, "SystemOut.log", folderPath);
                TextPage page2 = webClient
                        .getPage("https://****/view/ezspprodportal1/ezspPROD/WebSphere_Portal/SystemErr.log");
                exportFile(page2, "SystemErr.log", folderPath);
            }
            if (folderPath.contains("metintugpar0660")) {
                TextPage page1 = webClient
                        .getPage("https://*****/view/ezspprodportal2/ezspPROD/WebSphere_Portal2/SystemOut.log");
                exportFile(page1, "SystemOut.log", folderPath);
                TextPage page2 = webClient
                        .getPage("https://*****/view/ezspprodportal2/ezspPROD/WebSphere_Portal2/SystemErr.log");
                exportFile(page2, "SystemErr.log", folderPath);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException se) {
        System.out.println("IOException occured in logPageContent method: "
                + se.getMessage());
        saveLogException(se,
                "IOException occured in logPageContent method: ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out
                .println("Generic exception occured in logPageContent method: "
                        + e.getMessage());
        saveLogException(e,
                "Generic exception occured in logPageContent method: ");
    }
}

/**
 * Export the file to local path.
 * 
 * @param page1
 *            - contains the page information
 * @param filname
 *            - contains the filename in which the page content should be
 *            saved.
 * @param folderPath
 *            - contains the folderPath information.
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static void exportFile(TextPage page1, String filname,
        String folderPath) throws IOException {
    try {
        if (filname == null) {
            filname = "logs";
        }
        File dir = new File(folderPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("creating directory: " + folderPath);
            boolean result = false;

            dir.mkdirs();
            result = true;

            if (result) {
                System.out.println("DIR got created.");
            }

        }
        if (filname.endsWith(".log")) {
            filname = filname.substring(0, filname.length() - 4);
        }
        File file = new File(folderPath + "\\" + filname + ".txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it if
        file.createNewFile();

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.write(page1.getContent());
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("Done dowloading the file : " + filname);
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        System.out
                .println("Security exception occured in exportFile method: "
                        + se.getMessage());
        saveLogException(se,
                "Security exception occured in exportFile method: ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out
                .println("Generic exception occured in exportFile method: "
                        + e.getMessage());
        saveLogException(e,
                "Generic exception occured in exportFile method: ");
    }

}

/**
 * save the error information into the log file.
 * 
 * @param e
 *            - contains the error information.
 */
private static void saveLogException(Exception e, String errorMessage) {
    logger.error(errorMessage, e);

}

public String getPassword() {
    Console console = System.console();
    if (console == null) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't get Console instance");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    char passwordArray[] = console.readPassword("Password: ");
    String password = new String(passwordArray);
    return password;
}
```

}

Error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.StringBuilderWriter.write(StringBuilderW
    riter.java:138)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1681)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1659)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1636)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1611)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:668)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebResponse.getContentAsString(WebRespo
  nse.java:224)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebResponse.getContentAsString(WebRespo
  nse.java:195)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.TextPage.<init>(TextPage.java:42)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createTextPage(Defau
  ltPageCreator.java:304)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPa
   geCreator.java:170)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient
   .java:468)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:342)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:407)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:392)
    at LogFileAutomation.logPageContent(LogFileAutomation.java:289)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one of the log files you try to read is too big to be loaded to the memory.

```
TextPage page1 = webClient
                    .getPage("https://****/view/ezspprodportal1/ezspPROD/WebSphere_Portal/SystemOut.log");
```